# How to return boolean observable and check that boolean value

Tags: javascript, angular, subscribe

I want to use observable to be able to run my code synchronously, I want to return a true value after i get the icons from the server so that i can use it. How do i do it ?

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.addIcons().subscribe(data=>{
    if(data===true)
      //do something use the data

  });
}

addIcons():Observable<boolean>{

  this.Service.getIcons().subscribe(icons => {

    return  return observableOf(true);   
  });

  return observableOf(false);   

}
```

Answer (score 8):

You would use the [of](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of) and [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) operator from RxJS.

Your `addIcons` method becomes:

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'

ngOnInit() {
  this.addIcons().subscribe(data=>{
    if(data===true)
      //do something use the data

  });
}

addIcons():Observable<boolean>{
  return this.Service.getIcons().pipe(
    switchMap((response) =>{
      // do something with icons response
      // based on some condition return true or false
      return of(true)
    })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
addIcons():Observable<boolean>{
  const result = new Subject<boolean>();

  this.Service.getIcons().subscribe(icons => {

    result.next(true);
    result.complete();
  },
  error => {
    result.next(false);
    result.complete();
  });   

  return result.asObservable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your addIcons() function always returns an observable of false.
you first subscribe to getIcons() function, then returns the observableOf(false) and only then, the subscription occurs.

I'd do the following

```
private sub: Subscription;
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.getIcons$()
        .subscribe(data => {
            if (data){
                //do something use the data
            }
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
}

getIcons$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.Service.getIcons()
        .pipe(
            map(icons => {
                return icons ? true : false
            })
        )
}
```

don't forget to unsubscribe the observable subscription otherwise you'll have memory leaks.

Comment: observable can have a set of pipes they can go through. map is one of them. map iterates through the returned values